# How to redirect the output to a log file from upstart script?

Tags: 12.04, upstart, ulimit

I am using upstart to start/stop my c++ app server as shown below -

```
start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [016]

chdir /opt/tetra/app_server
respawn

post-stop script
  sleep 30
end script

limit core unlimited unlimited
limit nofile 8092 8092
setuid david
exec ./app_server --file=../config/data.init --port=8080
```

And I want to redirect the output of my server to a log file from the upstart script so what is the best way to do that? Does the below command will work?

```
exec ./app_server --file=../config/data.init --port=8080 >> /opt/tetra/app_server/queue_upstart.log 2>&1
```

So my script will look like this after this change -

```
start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [016]

chdir /opt/tetra/app_server
respawn

post-stop script
  sleep 30
end script

limit core unlimited unlimited
limit nofile 8092 8092
setuid david
exec ./app_server --file=../config/data.init --port=8080 >> /opt/tetra/app_server/queue_upstart.log 2>&1
```

Comment: Upstart already saves output to log files. Why do you need to do it yourself?

Comment: @muru ohh, do you know where that goes? I was not aware of this.

Comment: `/var/log/upstart` for systems jobs (those in `/etc/init`) and `~/.cache/upstart` for session jobs (those in `~/.config/upstart`) will contain log files named after the job.

Comment: @muru found the file, but tell me how these files are created? Does it create those file every day? Or it creates file whenever we restart them?

Comment: I believe it uses some form of log rotation (a new file is created whenever the old one grows too old, or too large).

Comment: Yep. According to `/etc/logrotate.d/upstart`, the log is rotated daily.

Comment: @muru If that's the case, then I don't see the logs daily. I just saw only two log and I am running this from couple of months.

Comment: change the log rotation settings, then.